# One single bootstrap dropdown-menu for multiple elements

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have multiple buttons. I want them to all display the same/single dropdown-menu element rather than having a separate dropdown-menu for each.

I was hoping I could utilize the data-target attribute to do so.

Further more, I'd like to be able to display this single dropdown-menu on any element. In my case, a th element in a table. I'm trying to get this to first work with buttons (and then maybe move on to trying th elements) so I copied this straight from the boot strap documentation and modified slightly, however it does not work. Is what I want possible with bootstrap dropdowns?

```
<link   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='row mb-1'>
    <div class='col-4'></div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-target='.test-menu' type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'></div>
</div>

<div class='row mb-1'>
    <div class='col-4'></div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-target='.test-menu' type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'></div>
</div>

<div class='row mb-1'>
    <div class='col-4'></div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-target='.test-menu' type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'></div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown-menu test-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

When I click any of the three buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: Could this be because you need to include jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `data-target` attribute in order to have multiple dropdown toggles to control the same dropdown menu. In fact, there is no `data-target` for dropdowns.

The trick here is to wrap the dropdown's toggle(s) and the dropdown menu with anything whose position is set to *relative*, i.e., `position: relative;`.

In the following example I wrapped them with `<div class="dropdown" />`.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">...</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">...</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">...</button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item">...</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">...</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/a0k7uqj1/28/

In order for the dropdown toggle and dropdown menu to work, they need to be siblings to each other. So I don't think that would work on any `<th>` element in a table, for example, because it has more nested levels there, i.e., `<tr>`, `<thead>`, etc.

Comment: Great idea! Many thanks. This would only work if the elements are next to each other (siblings), right? Which would be the case for me. For anyone that finds this, hoping to do drop-downs on elements that are not siblings, it wouldn't work, would it @david-liang?

Comment: @Mikey4Dice: correct, for bootstrap version 4.3.1 at least, in order for the dropdown menu to work, the toggle and the menu have to be siblings and wrapped by a relative position element.

Comment: Is there a way without them being siblings? Realistically, as in the question example, these elements are likely to be fairly not close in the tree.

Comment: @JeffPutz: Don't think so. You might be able to achieve that by writing custom javascripts to trigger the dropdown toggler.

Comment: Unfortunately, yeah, you can't do it without script, but in this case it's just a few lines using Popper.js directly, which is already there since you need it anyway for Bootstrap.